# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [128, 55, 11, 11], expected input[64, 57, 28, 28] to have 55 channels, but got 57 channels instead

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to train a Convolutional-Pose-Model (CPM) using Pytorch and in the below you can see the torch-lightning model along with the error I encountered. How do I solve this issue ?

#### pytorch lightning model

```
class CPM(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, k, verbose = False):
        super(CPM, self).__init__()
        self.k = k
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.criterion = nn.MSELoss().cuda()
        self.pool_center = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=9, stride=8, padding=1)
        self.conv1_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool1_stage1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv2_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool2_stage1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv3_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool3_stage1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv4_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)
        self.conv5_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(32, 512, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.conv6_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=1)
        self.conv7_stage1 = nn.Conv2d(512, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1)

        self.conv1_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(3, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool1_stage2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv2_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool2_stage2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv3_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=9, padding=4)
        self.pool3_stage2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv4_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)

        self.Mconv1_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(32 + self.k + 2, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv2_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv3_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv4_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        self.Mconv5_stage2 = nn.Conv2d(128, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

        self.conv1_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)

        self.Mconv1_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(32 + self.k + 2, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv2_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv3_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv4_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        self.Mconv5_stage3 = nn.Conv2d(128, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

        self.conv1_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)

        self.Mconv1_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(32 + self.k + 2, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv2_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv3_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv4_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        self.Mconv5_stage4 = nn.Conv2d(128, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

        self.conv1_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)

        self.Mconv1_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(32 + self.k + 2, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv2_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv3_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv4_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        self.Mconv5_stage5 = nn.Conv2d(128, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

        self.conv1_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(128, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2)

        self.Mconv1_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(32 + self.k + 2, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv2_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv3_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=11, padding=5)
        self.Mconv4_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        self.Mconv5_stage6 = nn.Conv2d(128, self.k + 1, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

    def _stage1(self, image):

        x = self.pool1_stage1(F.relu(self.conv1_stage1(image)))
        x = self.pool2_stage1(F.relu(self.conv2_stage1(x)))
        x = self.pool3_stage1(F.relu(self.conv3_stage1(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4_stage1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv5_stage1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv6_stage1(x))
        x = self.conv7_stage1(x)

        return x

    def _middle(self, image):

        x = self.pool1_stage2(F.relu(self.conv1_stage2(image)))
        x = self.pool2_stage2(F.relu(self.conv2_stage2(x)))
        x = self.pool3_stage2(F.relu(self.conv3_stage2(x)))

        return x

    def _stage2(self, pool3_stage2_map, conv7_stage1_map, pool_center_map):

        x = F.relu(self.conv4_stage2(pool3_stage2_map))
        x = torch.cat([x, conv7_stage1_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv3_stage2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv4_stage2(x))
        x = self.Mconv5_stage2(x)

        return x

    def _stage3(self, pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage2_map, pool_center_map):

        x = F.relu(self.conv1_stage3(pool3_stage2_map))
        x = torch.cat([x, Mconv5_stage2_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv3_stage3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv4_stage3(x))
        x = self.Mconv5_stage3(x)

        return x

    def _stage4(self, pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage3_map, pool_center_map):

        x = F.relu(self.conv1_stage4(pool3_stage2_map))
        x = torch.cat([x, Mconv5_stage3_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv3_stage4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv4_stage4(x))
        x = self.Mconv5_stage4(x)

        return x

    def _stage5(self, pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage4_map, pool_center_map):

        x = F.relu(self.conv1_stage5(pool3_stage2_map))
        x = torch.cat([x, Mconv5_stage4_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv3_stage5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv4_stage5(x))
        x = self.Mconv5_stage5(x)

        return x

    def _stage6(self, pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage5_map, pool_center_map):
        
        x = F.relu(self.conv1_stage6(pool3_stage2_map))
        x = torch.cat([x, Mconv5_stage5_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage6(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage6(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv3_stage6(x))
        x = F.relu(self.Mconv4_stage6(x))
        x = self.Mconv5_stage6(x)

        return x

    def forward(self, image, center_map):


        pool_center_map = self.pool_center(center_map)
        conv7_stage1_map = self._stage1(image)
        pool3_stage2_map = self._middle(image)
        print(pool3_stage2_map.shape, conv7_stage1_map.shape,pool_center_map.shape)
        Mconv5_stage2_map = self._stage2(pool3_stage2_map, conv7_stage1_map,
                                         pool_center_map)
        Mconv5_stage3_map = self._stage3(pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage2_map,
                                         pool_center_map)
        Mconv5_stage4_map = self._stage4(pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage3_map,
                                         pool_center_map)
        Mconv5_stage5_map = self._stage5(pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage4_map,
                                         pool_center_map)
        Mconv5_stage6_map = self._stage6(pool3_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage5_map,
                                         pool_center_map)

        return conv7_stage1_map, Mconv5_stage2_map, Mconv5_stage3_map, Mconv5_stage4_map, Mconv5_stage5_map, Mconv5_stage6_map
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        imgs, kpts, centermaps = batch 
        heats = self.forward(imgs, centermaps)
        losses = torch.tensor([self.criterion(heat, kpts) for heat in heats])
        loss = torch.sum(losses)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        imgs, kpts, centermaps = batch 
        heats = self.forward(imgs, centermaps)
        losses = torch.tensor([self.criterion(heat, kpts) for heat in heats])
        loss = torch.sum(losses)
        self.log('val_loss', loss)
        return loss
    
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        imgs, kpts, centermaps = batch 
        heat = self.forward(imgs, centermaps)[-1]
        return self.get_kpts(heat)
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr = 0.001)
    
    def train_dataloader(self):
        IMG_SIZE = 244 
        HP = HandPose(df, transform = transform, testSize = 0, imgSize = IMG_SIZE, subset = 'train')
        Data = data.DataLoader(HP, shuffle = True, batch_size = 64, num_workers = 4)
        return Data
```

#### Dataset

As for the dataset, I'm using [freihand](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/danieldelro/freihand) dataset from kaggle. I then used torch dataloader to load the dataset which returns original image, keypoints and centermap which is an image with its localized keypoints.

#### Error

```
/tmp/ipykernel_27/995635534.py in _stage2(self, pool3_stage2_map, conv7_stage1_map, pool_center_map)
     89         x = F.relu(self.conv4_stage2(pool3_stage2_map))
     90         x = torch.cat([x, conv7_stage1_map, pool_center_map], dim=1)
---> 91         x = F.relu(self.Mconv1_stage2(x))
     92         x = F.relu(self.Mconv2_stage2(x))
     93         x = F.relu(self.Mconv3_stage2(x))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1108         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    445 
    446     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 447         return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    448 
    449 class Conv3d(_ConvNd):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    442                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    443         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 444                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    445 
    446     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [128, 55, 11, 11], expected input[64, 57, 28, 28] to have 55 channels, but got 57 channels instead
```

Answer (score 3):

The error stack trace allows you to locate the error, it seems to come from the number of channels your `Mconv1_stage2`'s filters have.

There is a mismatch between the concatenated map you are feeding through `[x, conv7_stage1_map, pool_center_map]` and the number of filters the following convolutional layer expects (`32 + self.k + 2`). If this is the correct input, then you need to adjust the number of `in_channels` for `Mconv1_stage2` .